# System broadcast not delivered to the broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement a receiver that reacts to Bluetooth devices being connected or disconnected. However, I only receive the broacasts when the application is open.

I've added the receiver to the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BleReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And my receiver looks like this:

```
public class BleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "BleReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got intent: " + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

This works just fine when the app is open, but if I eg. use the task switcher and swipe the activity, no broadcasts are received anymore.

The output of `adb shell cmd package query-receivers --brief -a android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED` looks just fine:

```
Receiver #3:
  priority=0 preferredOrder=0 match=0x108000 specificIndex=-1 isDefault=false
  com.example.blelistenerapp/.service.ble.BleReceiver
```

Also, I checked the [implicit broadcast exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), and these two actions are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<receiver android:name=".BleReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I'm not interested in listening if the Bluetooth was turned on or off. Anyway, I tried and that action is not delivered either when the app is not active.